# Passing parameters with <>?

Tags: c++, arduino

I have downloaded the CmdParser library for Arduino and I ran across the following lines in the sample code:

```
CmdBuffer<32> myBuffer;

CmdCallback<5> myCallback; // Object for handling 5 function in SRAM
```

My confusion is regarding the `<>` (angle brackets). I've seen `<>` used on processor directives, like `#include <>`, but I've never seen `<>` used to pass parameters. Can anyone give a short explanation of what these lines of code actually do, and point me to a place where I can research this on my own?

Comment: This is pretty much as big of a can of worms as you could open in the C++ language: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters. Here ya go :-).

Comment: thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the context of CmdBuffer<32>, the angle brackets are accepting template arguments for a corresponding class template. Templates are a feature of c++ that make it possible to partially define a class (or function). When appropriate arguments are given, then the template is considered to be instantiated into a class, and the class in turn can be used to instantiate an object.

In contrast to function parameters, which can be dynamically provided at runtime, template parameters must be known at compile time. I.e., you can't use a non-const int variable to instantiate CmdBuffer to various sizes once the program is already executing.

The parameters of a class template can be either types or values. For example, the class template vector can be used to hold variable sized arrays of values, but only after a datatype is provided.

```
vector<int> aVectorOfInts;
```

In your example, the class template has a value parameter, rather than a type parameter. The value is being used to define the size of the static array for the buffer. It must be known at compile time.